# Mobile Storage in Angular

Tags: angular, local-storage

I am started to work on mobile angular application. Is there any possible way to store  data  encrypted such as token, usernames and passwords, and other needed data. 
Cookie and localStorage data can be handled by 3rd Party applications.
Thanks

Comment: "Cookie and localStorage data can be handled by 3rd Party applications." - but if they are encrypted then who matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies can be handled if you do not encrypt data but you can encrypt and decrypt by using `ng2-web-cryptography` by unique key.

The `angular-2-local-storage` library can be used as to store data on mobile side. Encryption can be provided by `ng2-web-cryptography` library by using enterprise level encryption (AES-CBC, AES-CTR, AES-GCM, RSA-OAEP).

To encrypt data in cookie or local-storage by using TOKEN generated by backend.

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage for local storage.
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-web-cryptography for encryption.

In below link, you can see all encryption types and difference.
https://diafygi.github.io/webcrypto-examples/

This library supports [AES-GCM](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#aes-gcm), [ECDSA](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#ecdsa), [HMAC](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#hmac), [SHA-256](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#sha-256---digest), [SHA-384](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#sha-384---digest), [SHA-512](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#sha-512---digest), [ECDH](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#ecdh), [PBKDF2](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#pbkdf2), [AES-KW](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#aes-kw), [RSA-OAEP](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#rsa-oaep), [AES-CTR](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#aes-ctr), [AES-CBC](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#aes-cbc), [AES-CFB](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#aes-cfb), [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#rsassa-pkcs1-v1_5), [RSA-PSS](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#rsa-pss), [AES-CMAC](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/#aes-cmac)